# React Context not updating Header buttons after user authentication, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently developing a web application using React on the front-end and Express.js for my back-end, where I'm implementing user authentication. I'm able to successfully register and authenticate users, and I generate a JWT which is then stored in a cookie. The problem I'm facing is with updating my header buttons based on the authentication state of the user.

In my React application, I have an AuthContext which holds the user's authentication status:

```
const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  
  // ...rest of the code

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, isLoading, error, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

When a user logs in, I update `isLoggedIn` state to `true`:

```
const login = async (username, password) => {
  const data = await handleRequest(
    axios.post('/login', { username, password }),
  );
  // ...rest of the code
  setIsLoggedIn(true); 
};
```

In my Header component, I use this `isLoggedIn` state to determine which buttons to show:

```
const { user, isLoading, error, login, logout } = useContext(AuthContext);
//... rest of the code
{!user && <Link to="/login">Login</Link>}
{user && <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>}
```

The issue is that after the user logs in, the Header buttons do not update. The user has to manually refresh the page for the buttons to update based on the new authentication state.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be happening and how I can get my Header to automatically update after a user logs in?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that the Header component does not automatically update after a user logs in. This happens because the AuthContext's state change does not trigger a re-render of the Header component. To address this issue, you can modify your code to ensure that the Header component receives updates when the authentication state changes.

One approach is to use the useEffect hook in your Header component to subscribe to changes in the authentication state. Here's an updated version of your Header component that incorporates this approach:

```js
const Header = () => {
  const { user, isLoading, error, login, logout } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(!!user); // Update the local state when the user value changes
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <header>
      {!isLoggedIn && <Link to="/login">Login</Link>}
      {isLoggedIn && <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>}
    </header>
  );
}; 
export default Header;
```

Comment: This is ChatGPT generated, which is forbidden at Stack Overflow. Please delete it before you get into trouble: we take acts of plagiarism seriously here.